# Make the Day of Week Variable Binary with Baseline

Tags: r, dummy-variable

I want to make the day of the week variable binary, but also have a baseline which should be Saturday.

I have tried the following, but this does not give me my intended result  at all. Is there a need to use a logical?
The range of the days of the week is 1 to 7, where 1 would be Monday.
First i renamed the numbers into the days of the week.

```
df$DayofW <- recode(df$dowc, 
                    "1"="Monday",
                    "2"="Tuesday",
                    "3"="Wednesday",
                    "4"="Thursday",
                    "5"="Friday",
                    "6"="Saturday",
                    "7"="Sunday")
df$DayofW <- ifelse((df$dowc == 6), 1, -1)
```

Comment: Here, the `(df$dowc = 6)` is wrong it should be `==`

Comment: Using `=` (an assignment operator) for comparison instead of `==` (a comparison operator) is a typo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that we are assigning (`=`) instead of comparing (`==`).  According to `?ifelse`, the first argument `test`

> test - an object which can be coerced to logical mode.

So, it needs a comparison operator

```
ifelse((df$dowc == 6), 1, -1)
```

Comment: When i do regression, does it show me that i set Saturday as the baseline? And was it correct to transform them from numerical to character?

Comment: @Amy if you need to add as baseline, one option is `factor` with `levels` specified in that order.  if it is a numeric column, it would be sorted based on the numeric value